# Audio channel selection

Tags: javascript, html, browser

The idea is to have multiple audio files streaming on a website and to set each audio stream
to separate audio channels. Alternatively, the audio could come from separate web pages, and even separate windows, and then filtered to separate audio channels.

As I understand it, audio coming from anywhere in the browser is streamed through audio channels 1 (left) and 2(right). The advantage of audio sources being streamed on different channels is the ability to access that sound data independently for further manipulation.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

Check this tutorial about creating positional audio with Web Audio API

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/positional_audio/

Web Audio API has required low level audio functions to mix audio channels freely.